# store data from java class file into a variable in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing an e-commerce college project where i have added the selected items in the cart using a java class file in which the calculation of total purchase is also done in a local variable , now i want the value of this variable (total purchase) in my jsp file.

what are the possible ways for this?

1. I have tried to create a session in my java class file, but failed because it does not rechognise what is request.

any other possible ways? Javascript?

Please help..

Below is some piece of code

**ShoppingCart.java**

```
public class ShoppingCart {
     public void display(JspWriter out)
     {
     try{
       java.text.DecimalFormat currency = new java.text.DecimalFormat("Rs #,###,##0.00");

      out.println("<table width='320px'>");

     double total = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++)
     {
         Item item = (Item)itemlist.get(i);

         out.println("<tr><td align=left> <b>"+ item.name+"</b></td>"+    
                "<td align=left>"+ currency.format(item.price*item.quantity)+"</td></tr>");

          total += item.price*item.quantity; 
     }
     out.println("<hr><tr><td colspan = 2 align=center><h3>Total purchase</h3></td>");
     out.println("<td align=left>"+currency.format(total)+"</td></tr>");

     out.println("</table>");

     }
     catch(IOException ex)
     {
         System.err.println(ex.toString()); 
     }
   }
}
```

**Order.jsp**

```
<%
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800); 
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if(action.equals("show")){
    try{
     synchronized(session)  
      {
       ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("Cart");

       if(cart == null) 
       {
        cart = new ShoppingCart();
        session.setAttribute("Cart", cart);
       }
       cart.display(out); 
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    out.println(ex.toString());
    }

    }

    %>
```

calling **order.jsp from **front.jsp**

**front.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="order.jsp" target="cartwindow">
<input type='hidden' value='show' name='action'>
</form>

<iframe frameBorder='0' name="cartwindow" style=" overflow: scroll ">
</iframe>
```

Comment: are u using ajax or forms?

Comment: Please share some piece of code that is relevant to this issue.

Comment: to Santino , i am using forms here..

Comment: @Shivam share some code

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone 
code shared.. help please

Comment: instead of simple class just use a sevlet simple and set it to the request scope or session scope

Comment: but to call a servlet method, i need request and response objects to pass to that method from order.jsp file..